# Memory efficient std::map alternative

Tags: c++, database, memory, stdmap

I'm using a `std::map` to store about 20 million entries. If they were stored without any container overhead, it would take approximately 650MB of memory. However, since they are stored using `std::map`, it uses up about 15GB of memory (i.e. too much).

The reason I am using an `std::map` is because I need to find keys that are equal to/larger/smaller than `x`. This is why something like `sparsehash` wouldn't work (since, using that, I cannot find keys by comparison).

Is there an alternative to using `std::map` (or ordered maps in general) that would result in less memory usage?

EDIT: Writing performance is *much* more important than reading performance. It will probably only read ~10 entries, but I don't know which entries it will read.

Comment: How big are the values compared to the keys?

Comment: which datatypes do you use as key / value? which queries do you need to perform exactly? is your dataset static?

Comment: Why do you need it right in memory and not processing in any database?

Comment: @Bathsheba uint64 vs 36 byte struct

Comment: And are you willing to sacrifice write-back performance for reading performance?

Comment: @m.s. The only query I've needed to use so far is "find values <= key"

Comment: @Bathsheba writing performance is by far more important than reading performance here (very little will be read, but I don't know _what_ will be read), but memory is more important than both :)

Comment: That is a *very* important consideration (perhaps modify the question to reflect that). For me it could well rule out a solution based on an insertion sort.

Comment: @stas.yaranov It could be in a database, but it's only run once (ideally). So the database would probably be deleted right after. Ideally, it would be run in-memory for performance.

Comment: @Bathsheba added :)

Comment: Will you read all 10 entries back in one go?

Comment: _If the data is all written before you perform any queries_ you could explore using `deque` (I usually recommend a sorted `vector` for this, but I'm not sure if your platform will give you 650MB of contiguous storage) to store all the data points as they come in - followed by a single sort operation, followed by queries using `upper_bound` and/or `lower_bound`

Comment: Reading in 20 Million entries for a total of 10 reads?  Where are you getting this data from?  Is it saved on disk and you're just reading it in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the issue *wasn't* `std::map`.

I realized was using 3 separate maps to represent various parts of the same data, and after slimming it down to 1, the difference in memory was entirely negligible.

Looking at the code a little more, I realized code I had written to free a really expensive struct (per element of the map) didn't actually work.

Fixing that part, it now uses <1GB of memory, as it should! :)

---

**TL;DR:** `std::map`'s overhead is entirely negligible for this. The issue was my own.

Answer (score 5):

One alternative would be to use `flat_map` from [Boost.Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx): that supports the same interface as `std::map`, but is backed by a sorted contiguous array (think `std::vector`) instead of a tree. Or hand-roll your own solution based on the same idea.

Its performance characteristic is of course different, due to the different back-end. It's up to you to evaluate whether it's usable in your case.

Comment: While this might reduce memory usage, insertion performance is much too slow (I would estimate several hundred times slower).

Answer (score 5):

Are you writing on-the-fly or one time before the lookup is done? If the later is the case, you shouldn't need a map, you could use `std::vector` and one-time sort.

You could just insert everything unsorted to the vector, sort one-time after everything is there (O(N * log N) as well as `std::map`, but much better performance characteristics) and then lookup in the sorted array (O(logN) as the `std::map`).

And especially if you know the number of elements before reading and could reserve the vector size upfront, that could work pretty well. Or at least if you know some "upper bound" to reserve perhaps slightly more than actually needed but avoid the reallocations.

Answer (score 4):

Given your requirements:

1. Insertion needs to be quick
2. There are many elements to read
3. Read-back can be slow
4. You only read back data once

I'd consider `typedef std::pair<uint64, thirty_six_byte_struct> element;` and populate a `std::list<element>`. That will be hard to beat in terms of performance.

For reading back, I'd simply traverse the linked list, checking at every point if you need one of those elements. That's a O(N) traversal but as you say, you'll only do that once.

Comment: Seems like the correct data structure given that list of requirements is one that's not in memory at all.